# Difficulty running method from different Class

Tags: java, class, methods

I am making a simple program that sets the title and name of an object: `book1`. Eventually, the goal is to have several books under the `Patron` class that will use the `Book` class to assign values. However, I am running into difficulty simply getting the `Patron` class to acknowledge the `Book` class methods.

Basic Tester/Main method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProjectFiveSix {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String title = "Bob";
        String name = "Hugo";       // name of patron (class assigning book)
        String author = "Rodrigo";

    Patron patronOne = new Patron();
    patronOne.setName(name);
```

Patron Class :

```
public class Patron {

    private String name;
    private Book book1;
    private Book book2;
    private Book book3;

    public Patron(){
        name = "";
        book1 = null;
        book2 = null;
        book3 = null;
    }
    public String setName(String name){
        return name;
    }
    public String borrowBook(String book1, String titleFinal, String authorFinal, String title, String author){
        if (book1 == null){
            book1.setTitle(titleFinal);    //**
            book1.setAuthor(authorFinal);  //***
    }
}
}
```

Book Class:

```
public class Book {

    private String titleFinal;
    private String authorFinal;

    public Book(){
        titleFinal = "";
        authorFinal = "";
    }

    public String setTitle(String title){
        titleFinal = title;
        return titleFinal;
    }
    public String setAuthor(String author){
        authorFinal = author;
        return authorFinal;
    }

}
```

Here I am getting "Cannot find Symbol" on both lines `book1.settitle` and `book1.setauthor`. The book has been instantiated and I cannot figure out the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: book1 needs to be declared as a Book not a String.

Comment: Thanks guys! Having the parameter - String book1 - makes little sense, changed it to - Book book1 - and I am set to go.

Comment: This might be a little beyond the scope of where you're at now, but using setters is a code smell.  You should prefer to set fields in the constructor.  Think about it: would you want to be able to change the title or author of a book in real life? So
`public Book(String title, String author){
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
    }`
Also, you should use some sort of list (like ArrayList) instead of hardcoding a certain number of book variables in the patron class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared your parameter `book1` (a `String`) as the same name as your instance variable `book1` (a `Book`).  To reference the instance variable, either name the parameter a different variable name, or use `this.` to specify the instance variable:

```
this.book1.setTitle(titleFinal);    //**
this.book1.setAuthor(authorFinal);  //***
```

Either way, you'll need to create an actual `Book` instance, or else your instance variable `book1` will remain `null` and you'll get a `NullPointerException`.